# Add a Field to a CrudController that ONLY passes values to Store / Update Methods

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm trying to handle how a field within a CrudController stores or updates the data on the particular model in a completely custom way. I would like the traitStore() and traitUpdate() methods to ignore this field entirely, but would like the data to still be passed in via the request. This is specifically in reference to a many-many relationship using a select2_multiple field.

I would like it so that the relationship ID's are passed via the request object to the Store or Update methods, but I DO NOT want the `traitStore()` or `traitUpdate()` methods to actually perform updates on that particular field reference.

For example...

I have this field within my crud controller

```
$this->crud->addField(
            [
                'label' => "Groups",
                'type' => 'select2_multiple',
                'name' => 'groups', 
                'entity' => 'groups', 
                'attribute' => 'title', 
                'model' => "App\Models\Group", 
                'pivot' => true
            ]
        );
```

And I'm overriding the Store and Update Methods like so.

```
public function store()
    {
        $this->crud->setValidation(UserRequest::class);

        // WOULD LIKE TO SAVE EVERYTHING BUT IGNORE THE GROUPS FIELD
        $response = $this->traitStore();

        // DO WHATEVER I WANT WITH GROUPS AT THIS POINT
        $groups = $request->groups

        return $response;
    }

public function update()
    {
        $this->crud->setValidation(UserRequest::class);

        // WOULD LIKE TO SAVE EVERYTHING BUT IGNORE THE GROUPS FIELD
        $response = $this->traitUpdate();

        // DO WHATEVER I WANT WITH GROUPS AT THIS POINT
        $groups = $request->groups

        return $response;
    }
```

Looking at my comments I would like to get a reference to the groups and handle updating the model however I want.

I've tried to unset the groups value in the request, `unset($this->request{'groups'})`,  but it still updates / removes the relationships when I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need to do to remove the references from being updated by the CrudController.

```php
public function update()
{
        $this->crud->setValidation(UserRequest::class);

        $request = clone $this->request;
        $this->crud->request->request->remove('groups');
        $this->crud->removeField('groups');

        $groups = $request->groups

        $response = $this->traitUpdate();


        return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to ignore/pass form field.

Example:
In your form fields have `first_name, last_name, gender` and in your database is only have `fullname, gender` then you wanna create/update the form, it will show `Column not found: 'first_name' not found...`,

How to fix it:

- Add `$fillable` in the model and fill the array data with name field that you want to store/update. In example case `$fillable = ['fullname', 'gender'];`
- Then, just use mutators inside the model too.

```
public function setFullnameAttribute(){
   return $this->attributes['fullname'] = \Request::input('first_name') . ' ' . \Request::input('last_name');
}
```

NB: You should have hidden field name 'fullname' in your CrudController.

```
$this->crud->addField(['name' => 'fullname', 'type' => 'hidden']);
```